# using proxy after tor

Tags: tails, help, proxy

I'm looking to use proxychain to make a chain connection LOCAL -> Tor -> Residential Proxy -> My VPS.

Could you please give me an advice how to configure the iptable to allow proxychain using tor.

Thanks at advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: You can enter a proxy in your `torrc`. If this is not want you want, please describe it a bit more.